# include_once inside function does not work

Tags: php

Inside a function I need to include a file. The file I need to include contains a query. The result of the included file is

```
<?php 
$list = $kenmerk_sql->fetch_assoc();
```

How should I make the include work? The way I do it now does not include the file.

```
function SelectTime($veld_uur,$veld_min,$naam,$startend,$selected=0)
{
include_once('./includes/getkenmerk.php');
$kenmerk = $list['bk_boekingen_kenmerk'];
Global $_POST;

$ret = "<select name='".$naam."'>
<option value='#' selected>Kies tijd</option>
<option value='#' disabled>############</option>\n";

$qry = "
                    SELECT
                        bk_tijden_id,
                        bk_tijden_titel_naam,
                        bk_tijden.bk_tijden_v".$startend."
                    FROM
                        bk_tijden
                    INNER JOIN
                        bk_tijden_titel
                    ON
                        bk_tijden.bk_tijden_titel_id=bk_tijden_titel.bk_tijden_titel_id
                    WHERE
                        bk_boeking_id=?
                    ORDER BY
                        bk_tijden.bk_tijden_v".$startend.",
                        bk_tijden_titel.bk_tijden_titel_naam
                    ASC";
    if(!$tijden_stmt = $connection->prepare($qry)){
    echo 'Fout in query: '.$connection->error;
    } else {
    $tijden_stmt->bind_param('i', $kenmerk);
    $tijden_stmt->execute();
    $tijden_sql = $tijden_stmt->get_result();
    }
    while($tijden_dienst = $tijden_sql->fetch_assoc()){

    $ret .= "<option value='".$tijden_dienst['bk_tijden_id']."' ".(($tijden_dienst['bk_tijden_id'] == $selected) ? "selected" : "").">".$tijden_dienst['bk_tijden_titel_naam']." (".date('H:i',$tijden_dienst['bk_tijden_v'.$startend]).")</option>\n";
    }
$tijden_stmt->close();  

$ret .= "
</select>";

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: That is already turned on, but the only errors re the missing variables ($list )
    Notice: Undefined variable: list in /home/jcslnl/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/paginas/boekingen/personeel.php on line 113

Comment: Try Global $list;

Comment: That you are calling `include_once` inside a function makes me think you don't understand how it works. Change the content of include_once to implement a function or a class which returns the dsirec value, include the file at the top of your script and call it from inside the function.

Comment: I have added a ! So if the qry is wrong, it should should show teh error.

Comment: I also added the Global and it fixes the problem. Thank you all very much

Answer (score 2):

You include could be simply loaded earlier, then content was loaded in script, but not in your calling place.

If you call `include` then you will add content everytime.
If you call `include_once`, will be loaded only once - rest of time, this will return null.

One of solution is to have defined function/class that will hold your data, you want.

Other solution is to have

```
<?php
return $kenmerk_sql->fetch_assoc();
```

and in you function:

```
$list = include( __DIR__ . '/includes/getkenmerk.php');
```

This way, you can always include you data, like script.

Comment: this works; include_once at the top of the script may not work in some cases like calling the function where the file is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try require() instead of include.